# Does ant 1.9.1 support java 1.8.45?

Tags: java, ant, version, compatibility

Does ant 1.9.1 support java 1.8.45. Is there a documentation to provide the compatibility details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java 1.8.45 is **not** supported on ant 1.9.1. Tried and tested.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. Java 8™ support was added to Apache Ant for version 1.9.1. See [this issue](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53347) which raised for that.

Comment: Patil: It specifies compatibility for JDK 8, but is it also available for the latest release i.e. 1.8.45

Comment: Well, I am not very sure about that. But ideally it should work for 1.8.45 because there are not gonna be significant feature changes in subsequent 1.8.* releases. You are gonna have to try it out.

Comment: java 1.8.45 is not supported on ant 1.9.1. Tried and tested.